# Problem query - execution plan

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, execution-plan, query-performance

I have a problem with a long running query, I'm not a DBA but it's become my problem. I've been doing a lot of reading over the last few weeks but for the life of me can't figure out why this query is running slowly.

It isn't always slow but it's particularly slow at the beginning of the month when we have a large amount of data inserted into the CMLEDG table.

The plan is here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BycGicsGX

Comment: Are you sure this is actual plan ? You need to give more info as what you consider as bad.

Comment: This plan only has estimates in it. For help with a query that's sometimes slow, see this Q&A: [Why is my query suddenly slower than it was yesterday?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204565/why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday).

Comment: How does the query run if you add OPTION (RECOMPILE) ?

Comment: Can you paste the actual query ? So we can identify if this is a code issue or server issue ?

Comment: Since it happens only at the beginning of the month when large amount of data is inserted,i think it may be due to wrong statistics.Once you insert the large amount of data ,do a statistics update and then check the performance.