# In what scenario would I suddenly need to recompile a Stored Procedure (SQL Server 2014 ENT)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I had an issue where a remote procedure call (from .net) for a specific parameterized stored procedure suddenly would end in a time out. This was the case for only some parameters being set not all. (typically most parameters passed to the stored procedure are null, except for 1 or 2 parameters, which have string values).

This happened suddenly. The stored procedure has not changed in ages. Indexes are well maintained for all tables in the database. I resoled the issue by adding WITH RECOMPILE to the stored procedure. But I am concerned, I want to know what triggered this behavior.

My question is:

1. What is/are likely causes of this and/or what potential issues
   should I be looking for?
2. Do I need to to check statistics are
   healthy (I let SQL Server take care of this for me).
3. Is there a way
   (and should I even be doing this) to pull a list of stored
   procedures that are at risk of this sudden broken behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: Start here: [Why is my query suddenly slower than it was yesterday?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204565/why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday).

Comment: Also you should be adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the problematic statement, not WITH RECOMPILE to the procedure. See Paul White’s post: https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options