# Slow query in production, bad execution plan or bad index?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, execution-plan, sql-server-2017, query-performance

I've just fixed a production performance issue by dropping an index and recreate it.
I suspect dropping the index also dropped executions plans that used it and one of them happen to be bad.

**Arguments in favor of bad execution plan :**

- Before dropping the index, I looked up the last update date for the statistics on the given table and they were up to date.
- My DBA has put in place [Hallengren's index and statistic maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)
- The slow query was a select statement executed from `sp_executesql` with dates parameters. Executing the same select statement without `sp_executesql` was fast, but also didn't use the same execution plan.

**Arguments against bad execution plan :**

- Before dropping the index, we went real wild and ran the forbidden `dbcc freeproccache` to clear any bad plan, but this didn't fix or change the performance issue.

**Note:**

- The slow query happen to be  using a table indexed by date. However,
  there is wide differences in the amount of records for each date. In
  other word, any given date range from few records to more than 100k
  and it is pretty random.
- The database is running under compatibility level 140 (SQL Server
  2017)

Was the source of the problem a bad plan or a stale index?
If it is a bad plan, then why `dbcc freeproccache` didn't work in getting rid of it?

[Plan before issue was solved](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16srQY5fivdl3dkzkvJ93SybiG48tiXZ3/view?usp=sharing)

[Plan after issue was solved](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jM5mMgQYOSwLMsUm4f-I3lstHsONvN_v/view?usp=sharing)

## Edit :

From what I know, this looked very much like a bad plan, but somehow `dbcc freeproccache` didn't work. So, I'm left in the dark, confused about the whole situation.

Comment: Which index? And was it exactly the same before & after?

Comment: @JacobH Yes was dropped and recreated. So, it is the exact same in term of spec, but when recreated, the stats are fully up to date of course, which is a slight difference. So instead of being up to date with this morning, they were up to date with now.

Comment: When you checked statistics (before recreating the index) what was the rows sampled vs number of rows in the table?

Comment: @dean The only thing I've checked is the last updated date.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a timeline of the events you described, as well as my commentary on what was the likely cause of your bad plan.

1. You're alerted of a slow query that was previously fast

Bad times, I empathize!

2. You go crazy and run "the forbidden dbcc freeproccache" and it doesn't help

Usually, clearing the cache fixes problems like this if the problem is [parameter sniffing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204565/why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday/204566#204566).

3. You drop and recreate a nonclustered index that's being used by the bad plan.  Now your problem is solved

Another reason for bad plans is bad stats.  If the problem is bad stats, then clearing the procedure cache will just result in the same bad execution plan being produced again (based on the bad stats).

Creating an index on a column creates new statistics on that column [`WITH FULLSCAN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments):

> Compute statistics by scanning all rows in the table or indexed view.

These are usually the best stats, because they include the most comprehensive view of the data.

Statistics can be automatically updated over time, as rows in the table are changed / added / deleted.  SQL Server will use different "sampling percents" based on the size of the table.  From that same docs page:

> For most workloads, a full scan is not required, and default sampling is adequate.
>   However, certain workloads that are sensitive to widely varying data distributions may require an increased sample size, or even a full scan.

It sounds like what happened was:

- an automatic stats update ran for this index, with a low or otherwise problematic sample rate
- this triggered the creation of a new execution plan, and that plan was bad
- you re-created the index, which produces good stats again

You mentioned you're using Ola's index and stats maintenance solution.  You may want to add a special case for this table / index to update stats with `FULLSCAN`, as it sounds like the table's data is skewed enough to warrant that.

If you want to avoid scanning the whole table (I don't know how big it is), you can experiment with different sample percentages (starting at 100, and dropping by 5 or 10 percent until you get the bad plan).

---

Looking the execution plans you provided (thanks!), you can see evidence for my theory.  Here's the index for the bad plan:

```
<StatisticsInfo Database="[BDM]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="
                [SubTypeInstanceProcessAdvancements]" Statistics="[AsOfDate]" 
                ModificationCount="288" SamplingPercent="23.4265" 
                LastUpdate="2019-08-15T22:00:09.91" />
```

And here's the good plan:

```
<StatisticsInfo Database="[BDM]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="
                [SubTypeInstanceProcessAdvancements]" Statistics="[AsOfDate]" 
                ModificationCount="0" SamplingPercent="100" 
                LastUpdate="2019-08-16T13:50:10.43" />
```

The bad plan has a sample percent of `23.4265`, while the good plan had stats sampled at 100% (because of the index recreation).

Comment: The part of the plan where it all seems to go wrong doesn't look related to that table though, the subtree in the bottom right joining `EstimateProcesses, BreakdownSubTypes, BreakdownSubTypeProcesses, BreakdownSubTypeProcessLocations` takes `0.798s` vs `1 min, 6 seconds` (at the re-partition streams) and has perfect estimates from the leaves in both plans.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yikes, I didn't notice that.  I didn't look really closely at the plan once I noticed the difference in `<OptimizerStatsUsage>`.  I'll take another look.

Comment: Not saying your answer is wrong though. It does have improved estimates from `SubTypeInstanceProcessAdvancements` - actual 4161 and perfect estimate vs 3088 estimate - maybe that causes the increased memory grant and that is sufficient to somehow prevent the catastrophically worse performance in that section of the plan.

Comment: @MartinSmith In the good plan, there's a bitmap filter (on the `SubTypeInstanceProcessAdvancements` subtree) that looks like it mitigates the problems with the rows coming out of that problematic subtree you mentioned. There's also an additional table joined in there (`SubTypeInstanceProcesses`) to which the bitmap filter is applied.  I guess the updated stats somehow guide the optimize to do that join earlier in the process.  The estimates are then wildly off, but on the high side (see good plan node 22), preventing the enormous hash spill (bad plan node 22).

Comment: That's my best guess at what's going on anyway haha.

Answer (score 2):

Why not both? A stale index with bad statistics can cause a bad plan to be generated.

Comment: Good point, the server is new. I'll ask the dba whe he added Hallengren's solution. May be the plan had been generated prior to this. However, if it is the case, why would `dbcc freeproccache` not have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The UpdateStatistics portion of the index and maintenance solution is set to `NULL` by default.

[image]

Comment: DBA does use `@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL'`