# Some timeout in query store but get all SP:Starting and SP:Completed in profiler

Tags: sql-server, profiler, query-store, timeout, troubleshooting

I have a report SP running. The user complaint report timeout sometimes. And I do get some canceled execution plan in my query store.
[image]

But in my profiler tracing file, every SP:Starting has its SP:Completed. Am I missing any? or could you please give me some direction?

Thanks,

Comment: BTW: The canceled query used the same execution plan as the quick one. It should not be the execution plan issue.

Comment: This should give you details about these calls. `SELECT * FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats
WHERE plan_id=2075`. Square plan id  means `Cancelled, which means that a client-initiated aborted execution.`

Comment: Thank you SqlWorldWide, I got the list of them with Aborted. Could you please share with me your experience about how to avoid this? BTW: Why the profiler didn't catch these aborted ones? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you capture queries when they finish with the `SQL:BatchCompleted` or `SP:Completed` trace running, aborting a query will show up as a finished query.

Lets say I run this query:

```
select * from master..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2;
```

And kill it end it after 2 seconds of executing: [image]

It will still show up in my profiler trace. What will be different is the error column. On normal executions it will show as: `0 = OK`. When aborting the query, it shows as: `2 - Abort`

[image]

The same is true for aborting a procedure, it will show up in `sp:completed`.

Avoiding aborted queries as they time out is finding why they took over 30 seconds.
One of the things you should read through is [Why is my query suddenly slower than it was yesterday?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204565/why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday).

You can post a new question to seek advice on improving the query runtime.

We would need the actual execution plan, table definition, ... (generally as much information as possible). I am sure that we would be able to help you with the reporting query.

Another band-aid solution could be increasing the time the queries are allowed to run.

> BTW: The canceled query used the same execution plan as the quick one.
>   It should not be the execution plan issue

It could be running with different parameters, resulting in parameter sniffing.
Adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the query could disable parameter sniffing if you are willing to live with the cost of recompiling the query on each execution.

Other reasons could be waiting for resources, such as being blocked, cpu / memory pressure, ....