# Slow database actions - moving in consolidated server

Tags: sql-server, cache

We are currently proactively correcting performance issues with a specific SQL Server by clearing the procedure cache nightly.

In the near future, we are intending to consolidate many databases onto a more powerful production SQL Server computer, and as such want to avoid clearing the procedure cache nightly.

What steps can we take to mitigate the plan issue without negatively impacting the consolidated server?

We have scheduled performance scripts on the weekend, however that’s not the solution either.

Comment: Start by identifying the query that gets a bad plan. Then paste its [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) XML here for analysis. Including query statement and table definitions are useful too. You likely have a parameter sniffing issue, bad statistics or poor indexing. These can be fixed, but good solution requires knowledge on what really goes on on the system.

Comment: And in the worst case, you can still remove plans from the cache at a more granular level, either per database or for a specific individual plan itself. But this is usually not the right solution to fix performance issues, and rather is a bandaid workaround. You should identify and address the root issues of your execution plans such as vonPryz mentions.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204565/why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my query suddenly slower than it was yesterday?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204565/why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday)

Answer (score 1):

To clear the procedure cache for a single database use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#f-clear-procedure-cache):

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION CLEAR PROCEDURE_CACHE;
```

But this is only a workaround.  On the new server you should use the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) to monitor for bad plans, and either remediate them with changes to the queries, stats, or indexes, or use the Query Store to [force](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-query-store-force-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) good plans.